# write a function to calculate all employees' customer satisfaction level?

Tags: r

So I have data about customers' satisfaction about our CS team service that looks like:

```
employee<-c("A","A","A","B","B","B","C","C","C","D","D","D")
incident<-c(1,2,3,1,2,3,1,2,3,1,2,3)##number of incidents
rating<-c(0,2,0,1,0,2,0,0,2,1,2,2)## 0 means there is no rating, 1 means "not satisfied", 2 means "satisfied"
data.frame(employee, incident,rating)
##satisfaction level for each employee= (number of "satisfied"-number of "unsatisfied")/number of all incident (eg. for employee A, the satisfaction level is(1-0)/3). for B, it's (1-1)/3)
```

I know how to calculate each employee's performance and plot it, but what if I have 1000 employees, can anyone help me to write a function which is able to generate the customer satisfaction level of all employees(and maybe have all of them in a single plot)?

Comment: ##satisfaction level for each employee= (number of "satisfied"-number of "unsatisfied")/number of all incident (eg. for employee A, the satisfaction level is(1-0)/3). for B, it's (1-1)/3)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the data that you supplied and adding a vector of the Employees one can do the following, assuming your `data.frame` is named df:

Create an employee vector:

```
EmployeeList <- as.character(unique(df[, 1]))
```

Then calculate the satisfaction level for each employee:

```
f <- c()
sum <- c()
for(k in 1:length(EmployeeList)){
for(i in 0:2){
sum[i+1] <- sum(df[which(df[, "employee"] == EmployeeList[k]), "rating"] == i)
}
f[k] <- (sum[1] - sum[2])/length(which(df[, "employee"] == EmployeeList[k]))
}
```

Which leaves us with a vector of the satisfaction level of each employee. Now we can visualize this using a barplot:

```
barplot(f, names.arg = EmployeeList, space = 0, ylim = c(min(f)-1, max(f)+1))
```

[image]

This would work with a larger dataset too.